# Sending exec output from function to main method

Tags: c, exec

I have a method I call from the main method called that executes `ls-l` on a certain directory, I want it to execute it and send the result as a string to the main method.

My current **flawed** code:

```
char *lsl(){
     char *stringts=malloc(1024);
      chdir("/Users/file/path");
      char * lsargs[] = { "/bin/ls" , "-l", NULL};
    stringts="The result of ls-l in the created directory is:"+ execv(lsargs[0], lsargs);
    return stringts;
}
```

Currently I am only getting the `exec` output on the screen, **I understand** why this is happening(`exec` getting called before reaching return point). However I don't know how I could possibly do what I want and if it's actually doable.

I was thinking of using pipes and `dup2()` so I don't let the `exec` function use `stdout` but I  don't know if it would be possible to put the output in a string.

Comment: You're looking for POSIX functions [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and [`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html).  Also note that `execv()` does not return if it is successful; it only returns on failure.  You'd need to use `fork()` before `execv()` if you were not about to switch to `popen()` — which does the forking and executing for you (and the piping).

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler , is there any more concrete example?

Comment: Did you look on SO for examples?  There's a tag `[popen]` (or [tag:popen]) which shows over 2000 questions and answers, though some are Python so you need to search for "`[popen] [c]`".  That gives you a mere 242 questions/answers to look at (I didn't add `is:q` to limit the query to questions).  Anyway, you should take a look at those.  The functions are pretty straight-forward to use.  Note, too, that C does not allow `+` as a way of concatenating strings.

Comment: And, just for your amusement, there are 639 questions listed by the query "`[c] -[popen] popen is:q`" (questions tagged C, not tagged `popen`, containing the word `popen`).  And when I rechecked "`[c] [popen] is:q`", it came up with the same list (242 questions) as when I omitted `is:q` — something changed in the way queries work when I wasn't watching.

Comment: Please, write a complete and verifiable example.  Just saying this doesn't work, and posting incomplete and unverifiable code does not allow to tell you anything useful.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonathan Leffler already pointed out in comments, there is no '+' operator for concatenating strings in C.

A possibility to dynamically extends strings is to use realloc together with strcat.

For each number of bytes you read from the pipe, you could check the remaining capacity of the originally allocated memory for the string and, if this is not enough, reallocate twice the size.

You have to keep track of the size of the current string yourself. You could do this with a variable of type size_t.

If you combine this with the popen handling, it could look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = popen("ls -l", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t str_size = 1024;
    char *stringts = malloc(str_size);
    if (!stringts) {
        perror("stringts allocation failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    stringts[0] = '\0';

    char buf[128];
    size_t n;
    while ((n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf) - 1, fp)) > 0) {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        size_t capacity = str_size - strlen(stringts) - 1;
        while (n > capacity) {
            str_size *= 2;
            stringts = realloc(stringts, str_size);
            if (!stringts) {
                perror("stringts realloation failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            capacity = str_size - strlen(stringts) - 1;
        }
        strcat(stringts, buf);
    }
    printf("%s\n", stringts);
    free(stringts);
    if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
        perror("pclose failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Question: wouldn't that code cause problem when used as a separate function? I want the function to execute `ls -l` and return the output as string but here the `return` function returns an error which isn't a string, so how would I possibly set up the function to return a different type depending if there is an error or not? is using return type `void *` an option here?

Comment: Your function could return a 'char *'. It would return the dynamically allocated string (stringts). The caller should then not forget to call `free` on the returned pointer after the string is no longer needed. In case of an error, you could return NULL from the function. Alternatively, instead of returning, you could terminate the program with an error code by calling `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several flaws in your code:

```
char *lsl(){
     char *stringts=malloc(1024);
      chdir("/Users/file/path");
      char * lsargs[] = { "/bin/ls" , "-l", NULL};
    stringts="The result of ls-l in the created directory is:"+ execv(lsargs[0], lsargs);
    return stringts;
}
```

- If you `malloc(3)` a 1024 byte buffer into `stringts` pointer, but then you assign a different value to the pointer, making your buffer to be lost in the immensity of your RAM.
- When you do `execv(2)` call, all the memory of your process is freed by the kernel and reloaded with an execution of the command `ls -l`, you'll get the output in the standard output of the process, and then you'll get the prompt of the shell.  This makes the rest of your program unuseful, as once you exec, there's no way back, and your program is unloaded and freed.
- You can add (`+`) to a pointer value (you indeed add to the address pointing to the string `"The result of the ls -l..."` and ---as the result of exec is nothing, as a new program is loaded--- you get nothing)  If `execv` fails, then you get a pointer pointing to the previous char to that string, which is a valid expression in C, but makes your program to behave erratically in an Undefined Behaviour. Use `strcpy(3)`, `strcat(3)`, or `snprintf(3)`, depending on the exact text you want to copy in the space of the buffer you allocated.
- Your `return` an invalid address as a result.  The problem here is that, if `execv(2)` works, it doesn't return.  Only if it fails you get an invalid pointer that you cannot use (by the reason above), and of course `ls -l` has not been executed.  Well, you don't say what you got as ouptut, so it is difficult for me to guess if you actually `exec()`d the program or not.

On other side, you have a `popen(3)` library function that allows you to execute a subprogram and allows you to read from a file descriptor its output (I recommend you not to `chdir` gratuitously in your program, as that is a global change in your program environment, IMHO it is better to pass `ls(1)` the directory you want to list as a parameter)

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *lsl() {
    /* the call creates a FILE * descriptor that you can use as input and
     * read the output of the ls command. It's bad resources use to try to
     * read all in a string and return the string instead. Better read as
     * much as you can/need and then pclose() the descriptor. */
    return popen("/bin/ls -l /Users/file/path|", "rt");
}
```

and then you can read (as it can be very long output, you probably don't have enought buffer space to handle it all in memory if you have a huge directory)

```
FILE *dir = lsl();
if (dir) {
    char buffer[1024]; 
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, dir)) {
        process_line_of_lsl(buffer);
    }
    pclose(dir); /* you have to use pclose(3) with popen(3) */
}
```

If you don't want to use `popen(3)`, then you cannot use `execv(2)` alone, and you have to `fork(2)` first, to create a new process, and `exec()` in the child process (after mounting the redirection yourself).  Read a good introduction to `fork()`/`exec()` and how to redirect I/O between `fork()` and `exec()`, as it is far longer and detailed to put it here (again)